# Pumping a Language does not imply regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I am currently studying the pumping lemma for regular languages and I am trying to come up with an example where even if the language can be pumped it is not regular. 
Which condition of the lemma should be broken such that I can find a language like that?

Comment: What do you mean "which condition should be broken"? The idea is that all the conditions *do hold*, yet still the language is not regular.

Comment: There's a [counter-example in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Converse_of_lemma_not_true), but it doesn't give any intuition as to how where this example comes from.

Comment: @Gilles nice.. i did not know of it either, so thanks :). And you should make this to an answer.

Comment: @user1704040 if you relax any of the conditions, the lemma won't hold, try to relax the three one by one, and see there's always some language 'fits' into it.

Comment: See the related [Languages that satisfy the pumping lemma but aren't regular?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9181/languages-that-satisfy-the-pumping-lemma-but-arent-regular). The remark of @Shauli was to the point here however.