# Non-regular language and pumping lemma

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

There is a non-regular language that exists the pumping lemma for regular language?

I didn't find one.

Edit:
 From what i understood the pumping lemma does not prove that it is a regular language becuse there are non regular languages that "support" the pumping lemma.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm asking for a non-regular language that if i do the pumping lemma about her it will give me true.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41442/a-non-regular-language-satisfying-the-pumping-lemma

Comment: "if i do the pumping lemma about her it will give me true." -- That sentence does not make any sense, as written. You want to say: I'm asking for a non-regular language that fulfills the condition of the (regular) pumping lemma.