# Proving that L is not regular using closure properties

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma, closure-properties

I need to show that the following language is not regular.

$$L = \{\ ab^jc^j\ |\ j \geq 0\ \}\ \cup\ \{\ a^ib^jc^k\ |\ i, j, k \geq 0 \ and\ i \neq 1\ \}$$

There is also a hint that it cannot be proven just with using the Pumping Lemma. Closure properties must also be used.

I'm having a hard time with this one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that it's reguLaR, not reguRaL.

Comment: Actually this is more or less the answe to "[Languages that satisfy the pumping lemma but aren't regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9181/4287)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ L_1 = \{\ ab^jc^j\ |\ j \geq 0\ \} $ and $ L_2 = \{\ a^ib^jc^k\ |\ i, j, k \geq 0 \ and\ i \neq 1\ \} $. Then

$$ 
L = L_1 \cup L_2.
$$

If we take 
$$ \begin{align}
L\ \cap\ ab^*c^* &= (L_1\cup L_2) \cap ab^*c^* \\
 &= (L_1\cap ab^*c^*)\ \cup\ (L_2 \cap ab^*c^*)\\
\end{align}
$$

Since $L_1\cap ab^*c^* = L_1$ and  $L_2 \cap ab^*c^* = \emptyset$, we have

$$
L\ \cap ab^*c^* = L_1
$$

Now, $ab^*c^*$ is regular, and $L_1$ is not regular (can be shown using the Pumping Lemma). If $L$ was regular, by the closure properties, $L_1$ would be to, which is a contradiction. Hence, $L$ is not regular.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a further hint. $L$ consists of two parts. One of them as a language by itself is not regular. Can you see which part?

Can you carve out that part as the intersection of $L$ with another regular language?

Comment: I posted a solution. Got it right???

Comment: Yes. $ \quad $.