# How do I prove a language is not regular using L′ = {a b^i c^i | i ≥ 0}?

Tags: finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I have just started my masters without any substantial experience in programming and I am struggling to understand certain concepts.
I have been given the following language $$L = \{a^i b^j c^k \mid i, j, k ≥ 0, \text{ if } i = 1 \text{ then } j = k\}.$$

However, I am struggling to find a way to prove that it is not regular using $L′ = \{ab^i c^i \mid i ≥ 0\}$. Also, what am I meant to do when I am given a pumping length of 2, and I have to prove that L satisfies the requirements of the regular language pumping lemma for strings longer than 2. I think I am a bit confused.

Comment: You are confused, but so are we. Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: This is a typical example of a language that is not regular, yet satisfies the pumping lemma for regular languages. A very similar example is given here: [Languages that satisfy the pumping lemma but aren't regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9181/4287). Same techniques. For nonregularity use closure under intersection of the regular languages. On the other hand we can always pump the first symbol of the string.

Comment: Here is how you can prove $L$ is not regular. Prove that $L'$ is not regular. Verify that the intersection of $L$ and $ab^*c^*$ is $L'$.  Note that $ab^*c^*$ is regular. Then use the fact that "the regular languages are closed under the intersection operation."