# How ot prove a language is regular using L′ = {ab(^i)c)^i) | i ≥ 0

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

I have the following language
L = {a(^i)b(^j)c(^k) | i, j, k ≥ 0, and, if i = 1 then j = k} .
How do I use the fact that L′ = {ab(^i)c)^i) | i ≥ 0 to prove that is it not regular?
I am given a hint that says that the regular languages are closed under the intersection operation, but quite honestly I have no idea what should be done.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "How do I use the fact that L' = .."?  Something seems missing.  What fact did you have in mind?  Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: There is a similar question here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148817/how-do-i-prove-a-language-is-not-regular-using-l-a-bi-ci-i-%e2%89%a5-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prove a language is not regular using L′ = {a b^i c^i | i ≥ 0}?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148817/how-do-i-prove-a-language-is-not-regular-using-l-a-bi-ci-i-%e2%89%a5-0)