# Which non regular language meets the requirements for pumping lemma for regular languages?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma, chomsky-hierarchy, theory

I heard in my lecture that there are non regular languages which meet the requirements for the pumping lemma for regular languages but I never actually saw one. Does anybody have an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Languages that satisfy the pumping lemma but aren't regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9181/languages-that-satisfy-the-pumping-lemma-but-arent-regular)